# Configuring redis with nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Question is I have a simple application that I wish to deploy to heroku the problem I am having is getting redisToGo to work with my app on heroku. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my app.js

```
var conf = {
    port: 8888,
    debug: false,
    dbPort: 6379,
    dbHost: '127.0.0.1',
    dbOptions: {},
    mainroom: 'MainRoom'
};


var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    socketio = require('socket.io'),
    events = require('events'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    redis = require('redis'),
    sanitize = require('validator').sanitize;

var app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = socketio.listen(server);
    server.listen(conf.port);

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
 });

 var RedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis'),
    pub = redis.createClient(conf.dbPort, conf.dbHost, conf.dbOptions),
    sub = redis.createClient(conf.dbPort, conf.dbHost, conf.dbOptions),
    db = redis.createClient(conf.dbPort, conf.dbHost, conf.dbOptions);
 io.set('store', new RedisStore({
    redisPub: pub,
    redisSub: sub,
    redisClient: db
 }));
 io.set('log level', 1);
```

I tried doing this but no luck.....

```
var conf = {
    port: 8888,
    debug: false,
    dbPort: 9685,
    dbHost: 'redis://redistogo:<pass>@sole.redistogo.com:9685/',
    dbOptions: {},
    mainroom: 'MainRoom'
};
```

I keep getting this error

```
 Error: Redis connection to redis://redistogo:<pass>@sole.redistogo.com:9685/ failed - connect ENOENT
```

I tried this as well and got it to connect but now it complains about Error: Error: NOAUTH Authentication required.

```
var conf = {
   port: 8888,
   debug: false,
   dbPort: 9685,
   db: 'xxxxxxxx',
   dbPass: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   dbHost: 'xxxx.redistogo.com',
   dbOptions: {no_ready_check: true},
   mainroom: 'MainRoom'
};

// Socket.io store configuration
var RedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis'),
    pub = redis.createClient(conf.dbPort, conf.dbHost, conf.dbOptions, conf.dbPass),
    sub = redis.createClient(conf.dbPort, conf.dbHost, conf.dbOptions, conf.dbPass),
    db = redis.createClient(conf.dbPort, conf.dbHost, conf.dbOptions, conf.dbPass);
 io.set('store', new RedisStore({
    redisPub: pub,
    redisSub: sub,
    redisClient: db
 }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the redis password using the `auth_pass` attribute on your `dbOptions` when using a node-redis client:

```
var conf = {
   port: 8888,
   debug: false,
   dbPort: 9685,
   db: 'xxxxxxxx',
   dbHost: 'xxxx.redistogo.com',
   dbOptions: {
     auth_pass: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     no_ready_check: true,
   },
   mainroom: 'MainRoom'
};

var db = redis.createClient(
  conf.dbPort,
  conf.dbHost,
  conf.dbOptions
);
```

If you take a look at the [API](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/master/README.md#overloading) you can see that `redis.createClient` does not accept a password attribute:

> redis.createClient(port,host,options)

And the `auth_pass` option is what you are looking for:

> `auth_pass` defaults to null. By default client will try connecting
>   without auth. If set, client will run redis auth command on connect.

https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/master/README.md#overloading